# SQL - Maintain integrity betwen 2 bridge tables

Tags: sql-server

[image]

I have 2 parent child groups:

- ProductType/ProductTypeGroup;
- Attributes/AttributeGroups;

AttributeGroups are also related with ProductTypeGroups, and Attributes are related with ProductTypes. I do this through 2 bridging tables.

However, the remaining dimension is that the 2 bridge tables must keep integrity too - Attribute and ProdcutType must stay true to their group hierarchy.

My first though, was to create a trigger on ProductTypes_Attributes that join the 6 tables together and checkes for existence but there could be easier or more robust solutions I'm not aware of as a SQL newbie.

I'd appreciate any advice with regard to better, or just alternative ways of managing this relationship.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So each product type belongs to exactly one product type group. And each attribute to exactly one attribute group. But what are the other relations? Each product group can have zero to many attribute groups? And each attribute group can belong to zero to many product groups? And each product has zero to many attributes, with the limitation that it can only have attributes belonging to attribute groups belonging to the product's product group? Is this it?

Comment: Each product type belongs to 1 'SuperGroup', and each atticute the same. Attributes can be applied to any product where it is permitted via its bridging table entry - so only if the ProductType and ProductTypeGroup match entries in the bridging lookup tables.

Comment: Sorry, I must admit, I don't understand your answer. Is what I have written correct or isn't it? If not, which of my statements isn't?

Comment: Sorry Thorsten - Yes, you have it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `ProductTypeGroupID` and `AttributeGroupID` into the `ProductTypes_Attributes` table.

You can then declare superkeys<sup>1</sup> on `ProductType` (`ID`, `ProductGroupID`) and `Attributes` (`ID`, `AttributeGroupID`), and reference these keys via new foreign keys from the `ProductTypes_Attributes` table. This ensures that these two new columns are always populated correctly.

You can then add an additional foreign key from `ProductType_Attributes` to `ProductTypeGroups_AttributeGroups` that ensures that the specific combination exists.

So, two new columns and 3 new foreign key constraints and then you can be sure of no invalid combinations. What you might need to do then is to replace `ProductType_Attributes` with a view that continues to only expose your original columns and then a set of triggers that maintains the new columns "behind the scenes" so that existing code doesn't need to be aware of how this enforcement is taking place.

---

<sup>1</sup>I.e. you declare a unique key constraint across both columns, even though `ID` alone is sufficient to uniquely identify each row, the usual criteria for something to be a key. This allows both columns to be referenced by a single foreign key constraint.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Damien - I'm taking a look at it now.

Answer (score 1):

You are using pure technical IDs per table. This has its limits when it comes to ensuring data consistency. Consider using compound keys instead. For instance: A ProductTypeGroup has a ProductTypeGroupNo. So a ProductType is referred to by the ProductTypeGroupNo plus a ProductTypeNo.

Primary keys are bold:

- ProductTypeGroup (**ProductTypeGroupNo**, Name)
- ProductType (**ProductTypeGroupNo, ProductTypeNo**, Name)
- AttributeGroup (**AttributeGroupNo**, Name)
- Attribute (**AttributeGroupNo, AttributeNo**, Name)
- ProductTypeGroups_AttributeGroups (**ProductTypeGroupNo, AttributeGroupNo**)
- ProductType_Attribute (**ProductTypeGroupNo, ProductTypeNo, AttributeGroupNo, AttributeNo**)

You see, now you can easily set foreign keys. The table ProductType_Attribute holds all key information to link it to ProductType, Attribute *and* ProductTypeGroups_AttributeGroups.

Comment: I see Thorsten - this is part of another learning process - so a little difficult to get my head around, specifically relationship patterns. Unfortunately, I also need to maintain some of the technical ID's as well due to the contraints of the ORM I'm using (Entity Framework)